# jQuery contradicting itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am encountering a strange issue with jQuery. I am generating a table with row with names:

```
<tr name='table-row-#'><td>#</td></tr>
```

where # is an index number (1 to 4 in this case) for as many rows as I fetch from my database [PHP]. I have even commented out and stripped down everything else to replicate the line above.

Consider this:

```
var keywords = $("[name^=table-row-]");  // Fetch all rows starting with 'table-row-'

alert(keywords.length);  // alerts '4' because 4 objects were found and printed whose name start with the string 'table-row-'

alert(keywords[0].name); // alerts 'undefined', which contradicts the first line
```

Any idea how this makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only form elements with a name attribute get a corresponding name property. A `tr` is not a form element so it doesn't have one, but you can still get the name attribute instead:

```
keywords.eq(0).attr('name')
```

For more information about the differences between properties and attributes see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6003819/772035).

Answer (score 0):

Someone commented and removed their answer "html elements to not have name properties".

This is the correct answer. I was copy/pasting my own functional code and was referencing the wrong element.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the `keywords[0]` part that is undefined, it is the `name` attribute of that entry.

Use functions like `console.log()` or [any other debugging method](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp) to see what exactly is defined and what is not.